# How to get a web page content in Android ?

Tags: android, html

I have a problem to get a web page content in my Android App. I would like to read the contents from this address https://szr.szczecin.pl/utms/data/layers/VMSPublic .

At first I tried to do it in Java using this code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String https_url = "https://szr.szczecin.pl/utms/data/layers/VMSPublic";
        URL url;
        try {

            url = new URL(https_url);
            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            print_content(con);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void print_content(HttpsURLConnection con) {
        if (con != null) {

            try {

                System.out.println("****** Content of the URL ********");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                String input;

                while ((input = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(input);
                }
                br.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

It worked after I downloaded and installed the certificate from that webpage. How can I do the same in Android?  I tried HTTPSURLConnection in Android but it returns me only the address of the web page. When I was trying HTTPURLConnection it gives me an information that document was moved (status 302).

Answer (score 2):

You can try following code:

```
 public static String getResponseFromUrl(String url) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); // Create HTTP Client
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL); // Set the action you want to do
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget); // Executeit
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); 
        InputStream is = entity.getContent(); // Create an InputStream with the response
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            sb.append(line);

        String resString = sb.toString(); 

        is.close();
        return  resString; 
        }
```

Comment: Keep in mind this function cannot be run on the main thread or it will cause errors. Drop it in a class that extends thread or as an async - examples of both can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to set target sdk as 23 in your app which is using Apache HttpClient for all the network related operations? If yes, here is a bad news. Android 6.0 (API Level 23) release removes support for the Apache HTTP client. Hence you can not use this library directly in API 23. But there is a way to use it. Add useLibrary ‘org.apache.http.legacy’ in your build.gradle file as below-

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

If this does not work you may apply the following hack-

– Copy org.apache.http.legacy.jar which is in /platforms/android-23/optional path of your Android SDK directory to your project’s app/libs folder.

– Now Add compile files(‘libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar’) inside dependencies{} section of build.gradle file.