# How can I get text data from websites and save in file using android prgram

Tags: android

[How to get a web page content in Android ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22170470/how-to-get-a-web-page-content-in-android)

this the link I found but it doesn't have a full description or explanation
Please suggest some method to it.

Comment: If it is possible send the zip file to my Gmail id.... veereshkotravvala333@gmail.com

Comment: Your question is too broad in scope. Please narrow it down. Be clear and specific.

Comment: use jsoup (https://www.mkyong.com/java/jsoup-basic-web-crawler-example/) , crawl to text , get the text and save to file .

Answer (score 0):

If you narrow down your question so defiantly it will better for me to answer.. But get web text data use Json parsing in android will help you and for saving you can use external storage through 'FileOutputStream'. i hope its clear for you. :)

Comment: sir.....my question is how to get string data that visible in web page(ex when we open web page some lines,passages are visible in browser) those string data should display in textview